# Hive query is not returning output

Tags: java, plsql, hive, bigdata

Hive query is not returning the data (0 number of rows).

need to retrieve 1 month back records from till/current date from the table.

```
select * from table1 
where date_format(order_date,'yyyy-MM-dd') >= date_format(add_months(current_date,-1),'yyyy-MM-01')
and date_format(order_date,'yyyy-MM-dd') <= date_format(current_date,'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

need to retrieve past 1 month data to till date.

Comment: what is in the order_date originally stored? Please provide some example

Comment: select * from table1 
where order_date between add_months(order_date,-1) and sysdate;
If the order_date is not a date u need to use to_date(order_date,'yyyy-MM-dd')

Comment: @praveena mohan could you please confirm if your issue was resolved?

Comment: Null occured becuase date column was defined as String hence below query helped.

select * from tables 
where date_format(regexp_replace(order_date,'_','-'),'yyyy-MM-dd')
between date_format(add_months(current_date,-6),'yyyy-MM-01') and current_date;

Thanks all for response!

Comment: @praveenamohan please approve the answer! And Upvote!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use "BETWEEN". Because you work between two dates and maybe more than performances

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_table
  WHERE your_date_column BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2019-06-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous answer, the following is the code which you should definitely be trying out

The `DATE_SUB` function in hive allows you to subtract dates by integers, thus 30 in our case denotes a month**

To cast your strings to dates, you may use `TO_DATE()` or `DATE()` functions.

** definition of a month varies with your use case. In this case, we are considering a 30 days gap as a month. If your use case requires calendar months to be considered as a month, use `add_months` function instead

```
         SELECT columns 
            from TABLE_NAME 
            WHERE YOUR_DATE_COLUMN_NAME 
                  BETWEEN DATE(CURRENT_DATE) AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, 30)
```